# How do I get elements in zoom area

Tags: highcharts

I want to find out the first element in the series in the zoomed area.

Let's say we have a chart with series:
http://jsfiddle.net/rathko/M7cfm/4/

```
$(function () {
    var $report = $('#report');

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        xAxis: {
        events: {
            setExtremes: function(e) {
                console.log("Print here the first element");
            }
        }
    },

        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

After zooming-in how do we find what is the value of the first element in the zoomed-in area?

Edit: I forgot to add, I would like to know the selected elements within the setExtremes() method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`events.selection`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.selection) method. You are given access to the axis min/max.
EDIT - Doing this with using the `setExtremes` is to use the `e.min` and `e.max`:

```
    events: {
        setExtremes: function (e) {
            console.log('event.min: ' + e.min + ', event.max: ' + e.max);
        },
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I forgot to add in the original question that I would like to find this out within the over event function, inside setExtremes()

Comment: Yes, I actually meant the value from Y axis of the first element. I believe e.min is the value of X?

Comment: Correct - in this instance. You would need to add the `events.setExtremes` code also in your yAxis.